# Find max/min of vector of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, max, min

What is the most efficient and standard (C++11/14) way to find the max/min item of vector of vectors?

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> some_values{{5,0,8},{3,1,9}};
```

the wanted max element is **9**

the wanted min element is **0**

Comment: `std::minmax_element` for the inner vectors.

Comment: Why not to use 2 nested loops? The other ways may be less readable.

Comment: @Jarod42 You mean to pass throgh each inner vector and call minmax_elemnt and then find the minmax_elemnt of the result ?

Comment: @SergeRogatch it is an solution. But I was wondering if there is an std function or pattern for this.

Comment: Just go over each vector and create two variables min and max and compare them

Comment: @gilad yes that is the last option for me. I was looking for something more clear

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: For the outer loop, it seems more complicated to use directly standard algorithm.

Comment: @Jarod42  I see... BTW, is not possible to benefit form the continuity property of storing vector in order to convert it to deal with it as one dimensional ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi a vector of vectors is not stored contiguously, each inner vector is stored in its own contiguous block of dynamically allocated memory so you can't really treat them as "one dimensional". You could change how you store your 2D array such that it is stored contiguously, then you might be able to simplify the implementation a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any efficient way to calculate the maximum element in a 2-D array(or vector in your case) involves a complexity of `O(n^2)` irrespective of what you do, as the calculation involves a comparison between `n*n` elements.Best way in terms of ease of use is to use `std::max_element` on the vector of vectors.I will not delve into details.Here is the [reference.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/)

Comment: Thanks but as I know std::max_element work for only one dimension? Or I am missing something... I will appreciate if you add a two line code that describe your idea. many thanks

Comment: pls have a look https://ideone.com/c8npHh. There might be some issues as i have not brushed up my c++ for a long time but the logic will work.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi modify it to your own use.

Comment: Aha, I see.. I thought that it is one line solution.. it seems that it is only solution :(

Comment: @HumamHelfawi You can't help it the computational theory will not permit you. But there is one more solution, Are you familiar with something called a max-heap? It can be used directly while the input is taken.Then you have a better time complexity solution of `O(nlog(n)`. Just for inserting the values.

Comment: unfortunately no, I will try to take a look.

Comment: It's actually just `O(N)` where `N` is the total number of elements to be compared. The fact that this is physically laid out as `K` vectors of on average `N/K` sub-elements is a bit misleading.

Comment: @TemplateRex is right. This is a linear complexity problem `O(n)`. I don't know why people are saying quadratic.

Comment: @pbible can you just explain to me why it is not quadratic ?. You need to compare  `n^2` elements to get to the correct answer.No matter what you do the complexity is not reducible beyond that.Its like the famous minimum number of races to find the fastest horse problem.

Comment: @Anony-mouse complexity of `std::min_element` is in terms of the number of calls to `operator<` compared to the total number of elements `N`. The fact that they are divided into several bins does not matter except for writing nested loops, but the nesting is not a "round-robin" tournament comparing every element to every other element. Every element is only compared to the min so far. For 100 numbers, you have 99 comparisons. For a 1000, you have 999. It's `O(N)`.

Comment: @Anony-mouse from my understanding of the OP's question he wants the max and min element of all doubles. Regardless of the layout of those elements, the min and max are found in linear time by examining them once.

Comment: @pbible You forget one basic fact it is a vector of vectors not a simple vector where the calculation could have taken something like `O(n)`. even if you try changing the data you need access to `m*n` elements doesn't he ?

Comment: @Anony-mouse complexity for the Standard Library's `std::min_element` is defined as the number of comparisons in relation to the total number of elements. It's been explained several times that the layout in vector of vector is immaterial here. So downvoted until fixed.

Comment: @Anony-mouse I think the nested data structure is throwing you off. If I have 100 elements, it doesn't matter if they are 1 list of 100 or 10 lists of 10. I still have to check all 100. The problem is linear in the number of elements regardless of how they are stored.

Comment: @pbible `{{5,**0**,8},{3,1,**9**}}` in a case like this it is conveniently 6 but if you want a generalisation based on the number of rows and columns, it would still be `m*n`.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm

Comment: @Anony-mouse rows and columns are irrelevant. The complexity is `O(n)` for whatever values of `r` and `c` where `r*c = n`. Personally, reporting the complexity as O(n^2) is misleading. I understand what you mean though. I just think it will confuse people by saying that it is quadratic just because you need a nested loop.

Comment: @pbible I have to go now.We can have the discussion tonight maybe(i.e if you are interested, I am). If he did not use a vector, then the simplest one would have been just to use a heap. But here since data is organised in a particular way and there is no chance to manipulate the input options, I believe complexity would be `n*n`. Have a look at the second solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637241/finding-the-index-of-largest-and-smallest-numbers-in-a-2d-array. First one is irrelevant as it manipulates the input.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a multi-threaded solution that returns an iterator (or throws) to the maximum for general type `T` (assuming `operator<` is defined for `T`). Note the most important optimisation is to perform the inner max operations on the 'columns' to exploit C++'s column-major ordering.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator max_element(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& values)
{
    if (values.empty()) throw std::runtime_error {"values cannot be empty"};

    std::vector<std::pair<typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator, bool>> maxes(values.size());

    threaded_transform(values.cbegin(), values.cend(), maxes.begin(),
                       [] (const auto& v) {
                           return std::make_pair(std::max_element(v.cbegin(), v.cend()), v.empty());
                       });

    auto it = std::remove_if(maxes.begin(), maxes.end(), [] (auto p) { return p.second; });

    if (it == maxes.begin()) throw std::runtime_error {"values cannot be empty"};

    return std::max_element(maxes.begin(), it,
                            [] (auto lhs, auto rhs) {
                                return *lhs.first < *rhs.first;
                            })->first;
}
```

`threaded_transform` is not part of the standard library (yet), but here's an implementation you could use.

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename UnaryOperation>
OutputIterator threaded_transform(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result, UnaryOperation op, unsigned num_threads)
{
    std::size_t num_values_per_threads = std::distance(first, last) / num_threads;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(num_threads);

    for (int i = 1; i <= num_threads; ++i) {
        if (i == num_threads) {
            threads.push_back(std::thread(std::transform<InputIterator,
                                      OutputIterator, UnaryOperation>,
                                      first, last, result, op));
        } else {
            threads.push_back(std::thread(std::transform<InputIterator,
                                      OutputIterator, UnaryOperation>,
                                      first, first + num_values_per_threads,
                                      result, op));
        }
        first  += num_values_per_threads;
        result += num_values_per_threads;
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads) thread.join();

    return result;
}

template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename UnaryOperation>
OutputIterator threaded_transform(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result, UnaryOperation op)
{
    return threaded_transform<InputIterator, OutputIterator, UnaryOperation>(first, last, result, op, std::thread::hardware_concurrency());
}
```

Comment: Note that fails if an inner vector is empty.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right, thanks. Should work (or throw) for all cases now.. not quite as pretty anymore :(

Answer (score 6):

If you used a `boost::multi_array<double, 2>` instead of a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` it would be as simple as:

```
auto minmax = std::minmax_element(values.data(), values.data() + values.num_elements());
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ifk2ueaKPlQvDEPK).

Comment: this is an interesting answer if boost is available. for me it is avaiable.. I am going to see it many thanks

Answer (score 6):

The plain `for loop` way:

```
T max_e = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
for(const auto& v: vv) {
    for(const auto& e: v) {   
        max_e = std::max(max_e, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Concise and clear. Best answer so far IMHO. Sometimes simple is best.

Answer (score 5):

You must at least look at every element, so, as Anony-mouse mentioned, complexity will be at least *O(n^2)*.

```
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> some_values;
    double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
    for (const auto& v : some_values)
    {
        double current_max = *std::max_element(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
        max = max < current_max ? current_max : max; // max = std::max(current_max, max);
    }
}
```

Comment: The complexity of searching for the minimum and maximum values is O(n), not O(n^2). The fact that it takes two loops to do it doesn't matter. Each element is examined exactly once.

Comment: Note that fails if an inner vector is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) function you could write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> m{ {5, 0, 8}, {3, 1, 9} };

  double x = std::accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), m[0][0],
                             [](double max, const std::vector<double> &v)
                             {
                               return std::max(max,
                                               *std::max_element(v.begin(),
                                                                 v.end()));
                             });

  std::cout << x << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

but I'd prefer the good, old for-loop.

The example can be extended to find both the min and max values:

```
std::accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(),
                std::make_pair(m[0][0], m[0][0]),
                [](std::pair<double, double> minmax, const std::vector<double> &v)
                {
                  auto tmp(std::minmax_element(v.begin(), v.end()));

                  return std::make_pair(
                    std::min(minmax.first, *tmp.first),
                    std::max(minmax.second, *tmp.second));
                });
```

<sup>(in *real* code you have to handle the empty-vector case)</sup>

Unfortunately a vector of vector isn't stored contiguously in memory, so you haven't a single block containing all the values (this is one of the reasons why a vector of vector isn't a good model for a matrix).

You can take advantage of a vector of vector if it contains a lot of elements.

Since each sub-vector is autonomous, you could use [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to fill asynchronously a vector of futures containing the max value of each sub-vector.

Comment: Nice. Just 2 things :  `#include <numeric>` for `accumulate` not `#include <algorithm>`. And you need to add an if in your lambda to handle an empty vector.

Comment: @MartinMorterol You're right, I've somewhat fixed the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you create a custom iterator to iterate over all `double` of your `vector` of `vector`, a simple `std::minmax_element` do the job

iterator is something like:

```
class MyIterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, double>
{
public:
    MyIterator() : container(nullptr), i(0), j(0) {}

    MyIterator(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& container,
               std::size_t i,
               std::size_t j) : container(&container), i(i), j(j)
    {
        // Skip empty container
        if (i < container.size() && container[i].empty())
        {
            j = 0;
            ++(*this);
        }
    }
    MyIterator(const MyIterator& rhs) = default;
    MyIterator& operator = (const MyIterator& rhs) = default;

    MyIterator& operator ++() {
        if (++j >= (*container)[i].size()) {
            do {++i;} while (i < (*container).size() && (*container)[i].empty());
            j = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    MyIterator operator ++(int) { auto it = *this; ++(*this); return it; }

    MyIterator& operator --() {
        if (j-- == 0) {
            do  { --i; } while (i != 0 && (*container)[i].empty());
            j = (*container)[i].size();
        }
        return *this;
    }
    MyIterator operator --(int) { auto it = *this; --(*this); return it; }

    double operator *() const { return (*container)[i][j]; }


    bool operator == (const MyIterator& rhs) const {
        return container == rhs.container && i == rhs.i && j == rhs.j;
    }
    bool operator != (const MyIterator& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }

private:
    const std::vector<std::vector<double>>* container;
    std::size_t i;
    std::size_t j;
};
```

And usage may be

```
// Helper functions for begin/end
MyIterator MyIteratorBegin(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& container)
{
    return MyIterator(container, 0, 0);
}

MyIterator MyIteratorEnd(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& container)
{
    return MyIterator(container, container.size(), 0);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> values = {{5,0,8}, {}, {3,1,9}};

    auto b = MyIteratorBegin(values);
    auto e = MyIteratorEnd(values);
    auto p = std::minmax_element(b, e);

    if (p.first != e) {
        std::cout << "min is " << *p.first << " and max is " << *p.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/khjYIj)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it pretty easily with Eric Niebler's [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library (which obviously isn't standard yet, but hopefully will be in the not-too-distant future):

```
vector<vector<double>> some_values{{5,0,8},{3,1,9}};

auto joined = some_values | ranges::view::join;
auto p = std::minmax_element(joined.begin(), joined.end());
```

`p.first` is an iterator to the min element; `p.second` to the max.

(range-v3 does have an implementation of minmax_element, but unfortunately, it requires a ForwardRange and view::join only gives me an InputRange, so I can't use it.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be to first have a function to determine the max/min elements of one vector, say a function called:

```
    double getMaxInVector(const vector<double>& someVec){}
```

Passing by reference (for reading purposes only) in this case will be a lot more time and space efficient (you don't want your function copying an entire vector). Thus in your function to determine max/min element of a vector of vectors, you would have a nested loop, such as:

```
    for(size_t x= 0; x < some_values.size(); x++){
        for(size_t y = 0; y < x.size(); y++){
            // y represents the vectors inside the vector of course
            // current max/min = getMax(y)
            // update max/min after inner loop finishes and x increments
            // by comparing it with previous max/min
```

The problem with the above solution is its inefficiency. From my knowledge, this algorithm will generally run on O(n^2log(n)) efficiency, which is quite unimpressive. But of course, it is still a solution. Although there might be standard algorithms that can find the max/min of a vector for you, it's always more accomplishing to write your own, and using the given will usually do nothing in terms of improving efficiency because the algorithm will generally be the same (for small functions that determine max/min). In fact, theoretically, standard functions would run marginally slower since those functions are templates which have to determine the type it is dealing with at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have a vector named **some_values**, as shown below

```
7 4 2 0 
4 8 10 8 
3 6 7 6 
3 9 19* 14
```

define a one-dimensional vector as shown below

```
vector<int> oneDimVector;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        oneDimVector.push_back(some_values[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Then find out a maximum/minimum element in that one-dimensional vector as shown below

```
vector<int>::iterator maxElement = max_element(oneDimVector.begin(),oneDimVector.end());
vector<int>::iterator minElement = min_element(oneDimVector.begin(),oneDimVector.end());
```

Now you get the max/min elements as below

```
cout << "Max element is " << *maxElement << endl;
cout << "Min element is " << *minElement << endl;
```

Comment: The two for loops are inefficient at all. reallocation is happening

Comment: I know it is inefficient, however I answered this question in order to help newbies who are learning cpp, and this answer focuses on functionality rather than efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<vector<int>> vv = { vector<int>{10,12,43,58}, vector<int>{10,14,23,18}, vector<int>{28,47,12,90} };
vector<vector<int>> vv1 = { vector<int>{22,24,43,58}, vector<int>{56,17,23,18}, vector<int>{11,12,12,90} };
int matrix1_elem_sum=0;
int matrix2_elem_sum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vv.size(); i++)
{
    matrix1_elem_sum += std::accumulate(vv[i].begin(), vv[i].end(), 0);
    matrix2_elem_sum += std::accumulate(vv1[i].begin(), vv1[i].end(), 0);

}
cout << matrix1_elem_sum <<endl;
cout << matrix2_elem_sum << endl;
int summ = matrix1_elem_sum + matrix2_elem_sum;
cout << summ << endl;
```

or optimazed variant:

```
vector<vector<int>> vv = { vector<int>{10,12,43,58}, vector<int>{10,14,23,18}, vector<int>{28,47,12,90} };
vector<vector<int>> vv1 = { vector<int>{22,24,43,58}, vector<int>{56,17,23,18}, vector<int>{11,12,12,90} };
int summ=0;
int matrix2_elem_sum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vv.size(); i++)
{
    summ += std::accumulate(vv[i].begin(), vv[i].end(), 0)+ std::accumulate(vv1[i].begin(), vv1[i].end(), 0);


}
cout << summ << endl;
 }
```